# When do I use ? to check for the existence of an item in an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what is the difference between:

```
if(object.mydataitem)
{
    //rest of code
}
```

and

```
if(object?.mydataitem)
{
    //rest of code
}
```

I just dont know when to use one of them over the other and what exactly is the functionality of the '?'.

Comment: This is all in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). The second will not throw an error if `object` is null or undefined.